# Applying one of an array of styles to each selected item

Tags: jquery

I have 3 (at the moment, could be more in the future) styles that I want to add to a group of divs in rotating order.

The classes I want to assign are:
.blue, .red, .green

and I have 4 divs that I want to assign them to in rotating order:

```
<div class="tripItem">
   ...
</div>
<div class="tripItem">
   ...
</div>
<div class="tripItem">
   ...
</div>
<div class="tripItem">
   ...
</div>
```

I would like the end result to be:

```
<div class="tripItem blue">
   ...
</div>
<div class="tripItem red">
   ...
</div>
<div class="tripItem green">
   ...
</div>
<div class="tripItem blue">
   ...
</div>
```

and to keep on rotating through in the same order if I was to add more divs.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: As a side-note: Don't use presentational naming conventions for css classes. Use structural naming conventions. What is blue today may not be blue tomorrow but the structure may not change. Reasoning and examples: http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-2-structural-naming-convention-in-css/

Comment: @Fraser: Cause I was bored I added the answers to a performance test , except kei's, it keeps crashing with an `undefined` error. No idea why, seeing it works in his fiddle. These are the results: http://jsperf.com/apply-array-of-styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a callback to  [`addClass` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
var classes =  ['blue', 'red', 'green'],
    len = classes.length;

$('div.tripItem').addClass(function(i) {
    return classes[i%len];
});
```

The [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29) is your friend if you want to rotate through a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 0;
var colors = ['blue','red','green'];
$('.tripItem').each(function(){
    if(num >= colors.length) return false;
    $(this).addClass(colors[num]);
    num++;
});
```

Comment: Yep, I noticed that. About to add code to make sure that doesn't happen but either way Felix's is more more elegant.

Comment: I +d your comment in his for recognizing it.  ;-P

Answer (score 0):

```
​var colorArr = ['blue','red','green','yellow'];
$("div.tripItem").each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass(colorArr[i]);
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BRfUg/)